# How to understand endianness in these function: 'writeFloatLE', 'writeFloatBE', 'writeDoubleLE', 'writeDoubleBE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, endianness

I know something about endianness, such as `0xdead`(using `writeIntLE`) can transform to `ad de`.

However, in these demos:

```
var buf = new Buffer(4);
buf.writeFloatBE(0xcafebabe, 0);

console.log(buf);

buf.writeFloatLE(0xcafebabe, 0);
console.log(buf);

// <Buffer 4f 4a fe bb>
// <Buffer bb fe 4a 4f>
```

and

```
var buf = new Buffer(8);
buf.writeDoubleBE(0xdeadbeefcafebabe, 0);

console.log(buf);

buf.writeDoubleLE(0xdeadbeefcafebabe, 0);

console.log(buf);

// <Buffer 43 eb d5 b7 dd f9 5f d7>
// <Buffer d7 5f f9 dd b7 d5 eb 43>
```

I don't know how to transform `0xcafebabe` to `4f 4a fe bb` or `bb fe 4a 4f`.
Help me understanding the steps, pls.

Comment: This has nothing to do with endianness. You're passing a number written as a hex litteral to `writeDouble` or `writeFloat`, which turn it into its 32 or 64-bit floating-point representation. That is, the transformation you observe is mostly from integer to floating-point.

Comment: @Touffy Can you post that as an answer, since that's obviously the answer. A quick test shows that BB FE 4A 4F is indeed the binary representation of the floating point number 3.40569E+09 (0xCAFEBABE).

Comment: @MrLister yeah, sure. I was hoping someone would post a better answer with links to floating-point specs. feel free to edit my answer to do that ;)

Comment: @Touffy I think a simple link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing (or not much) to do with endianness. You're passing a number written as a hex litteral to `writeDouble` or `writeFloat`, which turn it into its 32 or 64-bit floating-point representation. That is, the transformation you observe is mostly from unsigned integer to [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Floating-point means that a number is represented as *m*×10<sup>e</sup> where *m* and *e* are signed integers (well, technically the sign is stored in a separate sign bit).

In the case of 64-bit float, 53 bits are used for the digits *m* and the rest (11) of the bits encode the exponent *e*. JavaScript has only a single *number* type, and that's 64-bit floating-point. Therefore, its precision is only 53 bits (52 unsigned), which means it cannot store a 64-bit integer at full precision, by the way.

When parsing your code, the JavaScript interpreter will convert number literals (such as hex literals) to their internal 64-bit float representation. *That* number is passed to `writeWhatever` at runtime, not the original integer. I expect that if it's `writeDouble` there won't be any extra conversion (just byte reordering maybe).

Comment: Could you explain the transformation from unsigned integer to floating-point? a demo or a link. Thanks.

Comment: The unsigned int is immediately converted to a JavaScript number when the code is *parsed*, because JavaScript does not have native integers, only 64-bit floats. Just to be clear. Then that is eventually converted to 32-bit when evaluating the code. I've added to my answer the link provided by Mr Lister in his comment, in case you hadn't noticed it.